# Is light magnetically attracted and repelled from other light?

Tags: electromagnetism

If 2 photons are traveling parallel to each other would magnetism effect their paths?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Lorentz force $\mathbf{F} = q\mathbf{E} + q\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}$?

Comment: Check out Faraday Effect on YouTube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photons are not charged particles, nor do they have a magnetic dipole moment. As such, they are not themselves affected by external electric and magnetic fields.

Comment: Photons have oscillating magnetic and an electric dipoles. Both are perpendicular to each other and to the direction of propagation.

Comment: You are getting confused between the picture of light as oscillating electric and magnetic fields and photons. Photons have neither electric nor magnetic dipoles. If photons did have electric and magnetic dipoles, electromagnetism would no longer be a linear theory and the principle of superposition would no longer hold.